# How to write error message in a label?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to display error msg in a label and for that I am using the code written below but it says  "cannot convert type void to string."

```
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     conn.Close();
     LblException.Text = Response.Write(ex.Message);
 }
```

Is there a work around for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Response.Write` returns `void`. What you want to be the text is `ex.Message`: `LblException.Text = ex.Message;`.